# What's the current status of development of hedged ECDSA and EdDSA?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, dsa, nonce, standards

In the IETF Draft [Deterministic ECDSA and EdDSA Signatures with Additional Randomness](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-irtf-cfrg-det-sigs-with-noise/), methods had been specified to seed RNG deterministically with external input, to securely obtain a nonce for use in signing formula. The external input is variable to mitigate certain side-channel that may occur with *fully deterministic* signing.

However, the draft seem to have expired, with several security-related issue outstanding. I'm interested in implementing the said draft, but before that, I need to be certain that what it specify is something stable.

So what's the current status of that draft? I tried to follow the link to mailing list, but to no avail.

Comment: The main obstacles seem to be about IPR according to the 2022-08-05 mail from Alexey Melnikov.

Comment: I'd recommend doing it the [Soatok way](https://soatok.blog/2020/05/03/hedged-signatures-with-libsodium-using-dhole/) because then it's implementable with existing APIs.

Comment: @samuel-lucas6 That sounds interesting. But I'm planning to take a different approach for my suite. Specifically, 2 variants - 1 take a seeded PRNG and a random bits generating function; 1 take a nonce string (and its length, since it's in C) - the latter seeds a random oracle which is passed as the PRNG instance to the former.

Comment: That Draft RFC reads like a research paper to be honest. I'm not against such a scheme, but introduce it as a paper, not a standard. Standards should be for algorithms that have been researched and have seen some practical use.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I see some of us have some good opinion about the draft, so maybe bring the discussion to the CFRG list?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Also, the content of the draft seems pretty solid and standardization-ready, as the draft is basing the construction on that used by [XEdDSA](https://www.signal.org/docs), which as far as I can tell, was introduced as early as 2016.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interim answer. The technical aspects are meant as outsider comment and may be reposted to the CFRG mailing list when I subscribe to it.

### Bureaucracy Aspect

Although the draft is expired, the document is still in "Active RG Document" state. All? IETF drafts have maximum 6 months. Those merit further developent will see state change throughout its life.

The "Active RG Document" is defined as:

> This document has been adopted by the RG and is being actively developed

Where RG stands for "research group". (CFRG being the one we're discussing here).

### Technical Aspect

The updates the draft prescribed for EdDSA isn't intricate. From my experience implementing the draft, I find these issues for ECDSA.

**Problem 1**

The draft treats the HMAC calls as white box interaction across the boundary of HMAC-DRBG. The original intent of RFC6979 is to be able to reuse existing PRNG implementation *un-modified*, and the draft changed that.

Specifically, if the random nonce `Z` is variable length, then one of the following happens:

- the implementation make hosted calls to allocate memory for the seed material.
- the implementation penetrate the PRNG boundary and make individual calls to stream nonce and private key into the HMAC working context.

Those who has read NIST-SP-800-90Ar1 will know how serious NIST is about DRBG boundary.

Luckily for now, `Z` is specified to be fixed-length. And I've experimented with a 3rd approach,

- hash `Z` and construct seed material buffer in a statically-sized stack buffer.

**Problem 2**

The draft recommends KMAC when ECDSA is instantiated with SHAKE. But with one important detail missing:

- When generating output, do we use KMAC as a XOF, or fixed-length hash and call KMAC repeatedly?

And I ask this not to solicit answer, but to inspire to think, with Keccak, are we really satisfied with any of the NIST-SP-800-90Ar1 DRBGs? NIST had suggested the possibility of a permutation-based PRNG in the [last few slides in one of their presentations](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Hash-Functions/documents/kelsey_ches2013_presentation.pdf), shoudn't we push harder and request for one be specified? possibly after another public contest?

### Put up or shut up

For those interested in how the draft work in practice, I've implemented it in a [branch of my spare-time project](https://github.com/dannyniu/MySuiteA/tree/2023-hedged-dss).